# error in activation of django web application

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have created a virtual env that I named "f". It has been working fine for the whole time until yesterday when it gave me an error.

The code is:

```
import _imp  # Just the builtin component, NOT the full Python module
import sys

try:
    import _frozen_importlib as _bootstrap
except ImportError:
    from . import _bootstrap
    _bootstrap._setup(sys, _imp)
else:
    # importlib._bootstrap is the built-in import, ensure we don't create
    # a second copy of the module.
    _bootstrap.__name__ = 'importlib._bootstrap'
    _bootstrap.__package__ = 'importlib'
    try:python manage.py makemigrations

        _bootstrap.__file__ = __file__.replace('__init__.py', '_bootstrap.py')
    except NameError:
        # __file__ is not guaranteed to be defined, e.g. if this code gets
        # frozen by a tool like cx_Freeze.
        pass
    sys.modules['importlib._bootstrap'] = _bootstrap
```

The result of python manage.py run server is:

```
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 25
    try:python manage.py makemigrations
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help with the error?

Answer (score 2):

You have (accidentally?) pasted in

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

in that file after `try:`.

Remove that and you should be golden – and you should always be able to recreate your virtualenv from scratch anyway.

Comment: thank uu .. it work but I have another problem, in the same fileFile "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'